# Best usage of CameraX for MLKit Text Recognition on Android

Tags: android, firebase-mlkit, text-recognition, android-camerax

I need to implement text recognition using MLKit on Android and I have decided to use the new CameraX api as the camera lib. I am struggling with the correct "pipeline" of classes or data flow of the image because CameraX is quite new and not many resources is out there. The use case is that I take the picture, crop it in the middle by some bounds that are visible in the UI and then pass this cropped image to the MLKit that will process the image.

Given that, is there some place for [ImageAnalysis.Analyzer](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/camera/core/ImageAnalysis.Analyzer)
 api? From my understanding this analyzer is used only for previews and not the captured image.

My first idea was to use [takePicture](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/camera/core/ImageCapture#takePicture(java.util.concurrent.Executor,%20androidx.camera.core.ImageCapture.OnImageCapturedCallback)) method that accepts `OnImageCapturedCallback` but when I've tried access eg. `ImageProxy.height` the app crashed with an exception `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Image is already closed` and I could not find any fix for that.

Then I've decided to use another overload of [takePicture](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/camera/core/ImageCapture#takePicture(androidx.camera.core.ImageCapture.OutputFileOptions,%20java.util.concurrent.Executor,%20androidx.camera.core.ImageCapture.OnImageSavedCallback)) method and now I save image to the file, then read it to Bitmap, crop this image and now I have an image that can be passed to MLKit. But when I take a look at `FirebaseVisionImage` that is passed to `FirebaseVisionTextRecognizer` it has a [factory method](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/ml/vision/common/FirebaseVisionImage#fromMediaImage(android.media.Image,%20int)) to which I can pass the Image that I get from `OnImageCapturedCallback` which seems that I am doing some unnecessary steps.

So my questions are:

1. Is there some class ([CaptureProcessor](https://androidx.de/androidx/camera/core/CaptureProcessor.html)?) that will take care of the cropping of taken image? I suppose that then I could use `OnImageCapturedCallback` where I would receive already cropped image.
2. Should I even use `ImageAnalysis.Analyzer` if I am not doing realtime processing and I am doing post processing?

I suppose that I can achieve what I want with my current approach but I am feeling that I could use much more of CameraX than I currently am.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there some class (CaptureProcessor?) that will take care of the
>   cropping of taken image?

You can set the crop aspect ratio after you build the ImageCapture use case by using the [`setCropAspectRatio(Rational)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/camera/core/ImageCapture#setCropAspectRatio(android.util.Rational)) method. This method crops from the center of the rotated output image. So basically what you'd get back after calling `takePicture()` is what I think you're asking for.

> Should I even use ImageAnalysis.Analyzer if I am not doing realtime
>   processing and I am doing post processing?

No, it wouldn't make sense in your scenario. As you mentioned, only when doing real-time image processing would you want to use `ImageAnalysis.Analyzer`.

ps: I'd be interested in seeing the code you use for `takePicture()` that caused the `IllegalStateException`.

[Edit]

Taking a look at your code

```
imageCapture?.takePicture(executor, object : ImageCapture.OnImageCapturedCallback() {
    override fun onCaptureSuccess(image: ImageProxy) {
        // 1
        super.onCaptureSuccess(image)

        // 2
        Log.d("MainActivity", "Image captured: ${image.width}x${image.height}")
    }
})
```

At (1), if you take a look at `super.onCaptureSuccess(imageProxy)`'s implementation, it actually closes the imageProxy passed to the method. Accessing the image's width and height in (2) throws an exception, which is normal -since the image has been closed-. The documentation states:

> The application is responsible for calling ImageProxy.close() to close
>   the image.

So when using this callback, you should probably not call `super...`, just use the imageProxy, then before returning from the method, manually close it (`ImageProxy.close()`).

Comment: Hello Husayn. Thanks for your answers :) I've created sample repo where the code crashes with the mentioned exceptions. Should I file a bug on issue tracker? Repo: https://github.com/davidbilik/camerax-crash-sample

Comment: Hey @Billda. Just edited my answer. Should you file a bug? If you still think it's a bug, why not.

Comment: Hi Husayn, nice, that should really solve it .. I did not even thought about the super call because it was generated when I've overriden the method. I dont think its a bug now but maybe the flow is not really good since this can happen to anyone I suppose.